# How to find if an address belongs to the code or data sections

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Given an address I want to find at runtime without access the PE header on disk if it belongs to the .text section (Is there any other executable section?).
More details:
The address is in the same process that I'm running but it can be form a different dll static library or the executable that runs the process.
I'm running on windows using VS2010 Win32.

Answer (score 4):

You want [`VirtualQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366902.aspx). It fills in a [`MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366775.aspx) structure. If `mbi.Type == MEM_IMAGE`, you're looking at a mapped image. You probably also want to look at the `AllocationProtect` to check for `PAGE_EXECUTE` or one of its variants (otherwise you could be looking at something like read-only data mapped from the executable, such as a bitmap resource or something on that order).

Comment: Thanks, I checked it out but the problem is I found out that some rtti internal data structure address is actually in a memory with PAGE_EXECUTE_WRITECOPY attribute. Don't have a good explanation why though.

Answer (score 0):

Consider DbgHelp API: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679292(v=vs.85)

For example,

EnumerateLoadedModulesEx gives you information on loaded modules with base addresses and sizes
(so you can id the module)

MapDebugInformation retrieves information about module's sections