# Determine which process created shared memory in Windows

Tags: winapi, shared-memory

The system I'm working on has many processes running. In the context of shared memory, some are servers and some are clients.

They create/access the shared memory through `CreateFileMapping` and  `MapViewOfFile`.

I recently changed a structure on one of the clients, which led the client to attempt to map a region of shared memory which is bigger than what was created by the server process. The result is Access Denied.

My problem is, I have no idea which darn process created the memory in the first place. Is there a way of accessing such meta-information about shared memory in order to determine which server program needs to be recompiled?

To confirm, it is `MapViewOfFile` which is failing, with an error code of 5: Access denied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two types of shared memory exist: dynamic (using CreateFileMapping...your scenario) and static (memory mapping declared in PE Section(s) characteristics). One could test the existence of PE sections with shared memory characteristics on file and process level.

On the other side, the reason why [MapViewOfFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366761%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) failed might be other than the different sizes of mapped memory (e.g. credentials, offset of memory, ....)

Comment: take also a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10622750/how-to-find-if-an-address-belongs-to-the-code-or-data-sections